# Envelopes and Mailboxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

We suppose $n$ and $p$ are two positive integers.

A) In how many ways can you divide $p$ identical envelopes in $n$ mailboxes? (Each mailbox can hold several envelopes at the same time)

B) In how many ways can you divide $p$ distinct envelopes in $n$ mailboxes?

C) In how many ways can you divide $p$ identical envelopes in $n$ mailboxes, such that no mailbox remains empty? (it is assumed that $p$ is greater than or equal to $n$)

Any thoughts?

Comment: Non-zero integers can be negative. Probably something to fix.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any suggestions concerning the answers?

Comment: Not now (running out of time, and have to go). If you have thoughts of your own then I advice you to mention these in your question.

Comment: Well I've tried $ C^p _{np}$ for A) but trying values for n and p proved erroneous! In spite of that I think I'm on to something, even though I tried fixing it to no avail.

Comment: Try balls and urns.

Comment: It'll still be the same problem!

Comment: @GeorgeSaliba,I meant google "balls in urns".

Comment: I already know that type of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A and C) If you have $n$ **different** mailboxes, let $x_i$ be the number of envelopes in the box $i$. The number of ways you can put $m$ identical envelopes in $n$ boxes is the number of solutions to following equation:
$$
x_1+x_2+...+x_n=m
$$
If $x_i>0$, the number of ways is $\binom{m-1}{n-1}$, otherwise if $x_i\geq 0$,  the number of ways is $\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}$.

**Proof:** When $x_i>0$, Each case of putting envelopes in mailboxes can be represented by a sequence of $m$ number of $A$ and $n-1$ number of $B$ such that there is no two neighbor $B$s. For instance if we have $m=5$ envelopes and $n=3$ mailboxes, and if there are respectively $1,1,3$ in each box we can represent in by:
$$
A\,\,\,\,\,B\,\,\,\,\,A\,\,\,\,\,B\,\,\,\,\, AAA
$$
In this representation, the problem is equivalent to putting each $B$ only in one of the $m-1$ places between two consecutive $A$s (No $B$ in the beginning and the end of the sequence) and no two $B$s in the same place, therefore we have to choose $n-1$ places from $m-1$. When $x_i\geq 0$, it is enough to replace $x_i=y_i-1$ and the problem turns to the previous one.

B) If you have $m$ distinct envelope and $n$ **different** boxes, then you have multiply the previous numbers by $m!$.

**Proof:** The proof essentially follows the same idea with the difference that $A$s are distinct and there are $m!$ different ways to put them as a sequence.

Comment: Does your proof really take into account (for A) and B) only, not C) ) that there might be more mailboxes than envelopes? I've tried plugging in values for n and m and the number of distributions falls short from the actual one,e.g. : $n=5$ and $m=2$, if I use your method for $x_i$ greater or equal to 0 I get 6, while actually writing down each case gives me 15 different ways of distributing the envelopes.

Comment: Firstly, if you hava $n=5$ boxes and $2$ letters, then you have $\binom{5+2-1}{5-1}=15$. I edited the answer because there was a confusion in the answer about what $m$ and $n$ stand for.

Comment: Oh okay, great.